# Creating XmlNode with specified spread sheet type

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, namespaces, xmlnode

I'm little bit new in xml manipulation. I want to create a XmlNode.

I've already tried to OwnerDocument.CreateElement method and also tried OwnerDocument.CreateNode method, but I can't create the following XmlNode:

```
<Data ss:Type="String"/>
```

Can you help me with this problem? I already tried everything which I found, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`XmlDocument` has been superseded in the .NET framework by the newer `XDocument` API, which plays nicer with Linq and in general is a modern library to use for XML manipulation.

Here is an example how you can use that API to insert an element into an existing XML document, with an attribute that has a namespace prefix which is previously declared.

```
XDocument ownerDocument = XDocument.Parse("<OwnerDocument></OwnerDocument>");
XNamespace ssNameSpace = "http://whatever/somenamespace";

// add namespace declaration to the root, set ss as the namespace prefix
// you only need to do this if the document doesn't already have the namespace declaration
ownerDocument.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", ssNameSpace.NamespaceName));

// add our new data element to the root, and add the type attribute prefixed with the ss namespace
ownerDocument.Root.Add(new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ssNameSpace + "Type", "String")));
```

That will produce the following XML:

```
<OwnerDocument xmlns:ss="http://whatever/somenamespace">
    <Data ss:Type="String" />
</OwnerDocument>
```

If you are really tied to using `XmlDocument`, you can acheive the same there as follows:

```
XmlDocument ownerDocument = new XmlDocument();
ownerDocument.LoadXml("<OwnerDocument></OwnerDocument>");

// add namespace declaration to the root, set ss as the namespace prefix
var nsDeclarationAttribute = ownerDocument.CreateAttribute("xmlns:ss");
nsDeclarationAttribute.Value = "http://whatever/somenamespace";
ownerDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(nsDeclarationAttribute);

// add data element, and add a type attribute to that
var dataElement = ownerDocument.CreateElement("Data");
var typeAttribute = ownerDocument.CreateAttribute("Type", "http://whatever/somenamespace");
typeAttribute.Value = "String";            
dataElement.Attributes.Append(typeAttribute);

// append to main document
ownerDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(dataElement);
```